# Can't start apps after long periods of leaving on

Tags: release-freya, system, apps

I'm new to Linux so go easy on me, this is my first time working with Linux, after giving up completely on Windows. The nearest experience I have with Unix is my Macs.

I have a habit of leaving my desktop pc on 24/7 with a shut down once every 2-3 months. Of course this had Windows on it in the past. I gave up with Windows 10 and decided to give Linux a try, and Elementary OS was just too beautiful to give up.

I stumbled on a few problems installing but everything is fine now, it installed alright and have no problems, for the most part. Now in the settings, I've set my power option to turn off screen after 30 minutes and **never sleep**. I do a lot of data transfers uploading to multiple servers for work so it does that all night and day when it had Windows.

Now, I noticed if I leave it on after some time, the apps on the system doesn't seem to want to start. For example, the stock apps like video, photos, calendar doesn't want to start. I've installed Chrome and that also doesn't start. Nothing starts unless I reboot the computer, and even then, sometimes the reboot button doesn't do anything and I have to reboot from the power button on my desktop.

I'm not sure if this is typical Linux behaviour, cause I know for a fact Linux is widely favoured by many to be used as a server. Is there a setting or something I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
After having this happen everytime I leave it idle for a long time, I've decided to turn off the "Turn off screen after x hours" feature to never. That alleviated the apps not opening but the next problem if I have that on is my cursor goes completely missing.

Comment: That's not a typical behaviour. Do you see the mouse cursor and/or the animations if you click on the dock at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: @bigbang That's exactly my thoughts as well. I do se the mouse cursor, and if I click on let's say the settings app of some other app on the dock or application window, I see the animation of it, like on the dock it bounces, normally the window pops up, but not when it's like _stuck_. (Stuck = left overnight then apps don't open)